# Write an mongo dB query to print details of the Workers who are also Managers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

[Worker collection][1]

[Title collection][2]

Worker Collection

```
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 001 , "first_name" : "Monika" , "last_name" : "Arora" , "salary" : 100000 ,  "joining_date" : "2016-02-20 09:00:00" , "department" : "Hr" } )
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 002 , "first_name" : "Niharika" , "last_name":"Verma","salary":75000,"joining_date":"2016-04-20 09:00:00","department":"Admin"})
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 003 , "first_name" : "Vishal" , "last_name":"Singhal","salary":70000,"joining_date":"2016-02-20 09:00:00","department":"Hr"})
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 004 , "first_name" : "Amitabh" , "last_name":"Singh","salary":500000,"joining_date":"2016-02-20 09:00:00","department":"Admin"})
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 005 , "first_name" : "Vipul" , "last_name":"Diwan","salary":200000,"joining_date":"2016-02-20 09:00:00","department":"Account"})
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 006 , "first_name" : "Satish" , "last_name":"Kumar","salary":75000,"joining_date":"2016-04-20 09:00:00","department":"Account"})
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 007 , "first_name" : "Vivek" , "last_name":"Bhati","salary":50000,"joining_date":"2016-06-11 09:00:00","department":"Admin"})
db.worker.insert( { "worker_id" : 008 , "first_name" : "Geetika" , "last_name" : "Chauhan" , "salary" : 90000 ,  "joining_date" : "2016-04-11 09:00:00" , "department" : "Admin" } )
```

Title collection

```
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :1 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Manager" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-02-20" } )
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :2 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Executive" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-06-11" } )
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :3 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Lead" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-06-11" } )
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :4 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Asst.Manager" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-06-11" } )
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :5 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Manager" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-06-11" } )
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :6 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Lead" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-06-11" } )
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :7 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Executive" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-06-11" } )
db.title.insert ( { "WORKER_REF_ID" :8 , "WORKER_TITLE" : "Executive" , "AFFECTED_FROM" : "2019-06-11" } )
```

Output:

FIRST_NAME                                         WORKER_TITLE

---

Monika                                             Manager
Vivek                                              Manager

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you include the expected output? Meanwhile, both images can be removed since these are the data you have posted as snippets. We don't encourage to post code/data as images.

Comment: ... and does `"Asst.Manager"` count as a "Manager"?

Comment: No, Only Manager has to come.

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation pipeline will provide the desired output if workers only have one title.

```
db.worker.aggregate(
    [
        {
            // join workers and titles on worker_id
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "title",
                "localField": "worker_id",
                "foreignField": "WORKER_REF_ID",
                "as": "title"
            }
        },
        {
            // unwind new title field from array to object
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$title"
            }
        },
        {
            // get only managers
            "$match": {
                "title.WORKER_TITLE": "Manager"
            }
        },
        {
            // display desired output
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "first_name": 1,
                "title": "$title.WORKER_TITLE"
            }
        }
    ])
```

The output will look like this. I think your expected output should show Vipul, not Vivek, as the second manager.

```
{ 
    "first_name" : "Monika", 
    "title" : "Manager"
}
{ 
    "first_name" : "Vipul", 
    "title" : "Manager"
}
```